# Unittest in kotlin can't return value

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

I'm studying unit test, my first test project is lotto, so I wanna get six numbers using test.

I don't understand my error, where should I fix this code? `getRandom` is a method to get 1~45 number.
And getSixNumber is to get six numbers avoiding duplicated number using Set.

```
    @Test
    fun isSixNumber(){
        var numbers = getSixNumber()
        println(numbers)
        assertEquals(6,numbers.size)
    }

    @Test
    fun getSixNumber() : Set<Int> {
        var lottoNum = setOf<Int>(6)
        while(lottoNum.size!=6){
            lottoNum.plus(getRandom())
        }
        return lottoNum
    }


    fun getRandom():Int{
        return Random().nextInt(45)+1
    }
```

```
ERROR

java.lang.Exception: Method getSixNumber() should be void

    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoid(FrameworkMethod.java:99)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:155)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:208)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:188)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Remove the Test decorator from getSixNumbers. The error tells you all functions marked with Test should return void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in Java, unit test methods aren't returning any value (void), mainly because it's a **unit** test and it results shouldn't be required/related to other tests,

Your fix is to remove return type:

```
@Test
fun getSixNumber() {
    var lottoNum = setOf<Int>(6)
    while(lottoNum.size!=6){
        lottoNum.plus(getRandom())
    }
    return lottoNum
}
```